# Unity sprite renderer uses standard 2D sprite instead of custom loaded one

Tags: sprites, unity

I have loaded a 2D sprite from the filesystem and created a sprite from it, which I then attach to a SpriteRenderer. The game object appears in the scene but for some reason it doesn't seem to be using the sprite I loaded, and is instead using the Standard Assets/2D/Materials/SpriteLift sprite. I have attached my sprite creation code and some screenshots:

```
public static Sprite LoadSprite(string relPath) {
    var fileUrl = "file://D:/Unity Projects/2D-Game/mod/base/textures/" + relPath + ".png";

    // Download texture from file location and resize it
    var www = new WWW (fileUrl);
    var texture = www.texture;
    texture.Resize (textureSize, textureSize);
    texture.name = relPath;
    Debug.Log (texture);

    // Make the sprite
    var sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, spriteRect, spritePivot, textureSize);
    sprite.name = relPath;
    return sprite;
}
```

The Unity scene with the incorrect sprite:
[image]

The desired texture:
[image]

The code that creates the game object and attaches the loaded sprite to the SpriteRenderer:

```
GameObject go = new GameObject ();
go.name = "Tile_ " + tile.location.ToString();
go.transform.position = tile.location.ToVector3 ();
go.transform.SetParent (this.transform, true);
SpriteRenderer sr = go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
sr.sprite = tile.Type.sprite;
sr.enabled = true;
```

Note that the screenshot contains many game objects all with the same sprite, that's why it looks big in the scene.

**EDIT:** The problem may be due to materials.

**EDIT 2:** Screenshot of a selected tile:

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that LoadSprite is executed before
    sr.sprite = tile.Type.sprite; 
is called?
Sometimes you will need to make use of Script Execution Order to make sure things happen correctly.

Comment: @Allen Yep, LoadSprite is in a class that isn't attached to a game object, and is called by a script that is attached to a master game object, before the tile game objects are made. I have a hunch that the problem may be due to materials.

Comment: With that hunch, can you give us a shot with one of tiles selected so that we can see the SpriteRender component and Shader?

Comment: @Allen I've added a screenshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies, I should have picked up on this quicker. Instead I made you get a screenshot that wasn't needed.

Your not waiting for your WWW to complete before creating the sprite. So basically the www.texture is empty at the time you use it. Check www.isDone before working with the texture to see what I mean.

If you do not want to do this in a Coroutine (yield return www;), you can block until it is done, but this is not recommended. By blocking I mean something like "while(!www.isDone){ // Do nothing }".

See the [WWW documention](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) for more information, looking at the example.